# Trying to add a star mark in a table before turning it to a graph

Tags: r

I am trying to show in a forest plot which lines are statiscially significant after multiple testing correction. For that I have tried multiple ways to introduce a star mark in my y axis legend without success. My last try was to create a for loop with an ifelse condition inside to create a new vector (P_bis2) in my table (gen_cor0) that would add a star mark to the original vector (P_bis) when the p value (p) is below my threshold (9e-4):

```
for(i in 1:52) {
    if(gen_cor0$p<9e-4){
    gen_cor0$P_bis2<-paste0(gen_cor0$P_bis,"*")
    } else {
        gen_cor0$P_bis2<-paste0(gen_cor0$P_bis)
        }
}
```

Thank you very much for any help you can give

Comment: It is hard to understand you without a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) minimal data set. But the first thing I can see in your codes, you use `i` inside the `for` but you never use it in your code block like `gen_cor0$P_bis[i]`   ,  `gen_cor0$p[i]`   and   `gen_cor0$P_bis2[i]` etc.

Comment: That is my problem, I don't understand how to use it

Comment: By the way, you don't need a loop : `gen_cor0$P_bis2 <- ifelse(gen_cor0$p<9e-4, paste0(gen_cor0$P_bis,"*"), gen_cor0$P_bis)`